# Don't understand python pop altering multiple variables

Tags: python, list

I'm sure this is something simple that I've overlooked, but I'm hoping someone can explain the following to me:

```
origList = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
def test(inputList):
    while range(len(inputList)):
        inputList.pop()
altList = origList
test(altList)
print 'origList:', origList # prints origList: []
print 'altList:', altList # prints origList: []
```

I thought I understood list.pop(), but what I don't understand is why the original list is modified if I'm only 'popping' the elements of the alternate list...

Comment: `while range(len(inputList)):` is horrendously slower than `while len(inputList):` which is horrendously slower than `while inputList:`

Comment: as ignacio said: @garen, Don't forget to select the answer you believe to be most appropriate

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Everything in Python is a reference. They're the same list.

```
altList = origList[:]
```

Comment: @garen: Don't forget to select the answer you believe to be most appropriate.

Answer (score 3):

It's because the line:

```
altList = origList
```

does not create a copy of the origList object. Both names, will refer to the same underlying object. To create a copy, see the [copy module](http://docs.python.org/library/copy.html).

Answer (score 2):

this is because when you say

```
altList = origList
```

you're actually pointing the location of altList to the location of origList (since everything in python is an object). effectively, equality here means "make these the same object" instead of give them the same values.

Answer (score 1):

The "problem" is this line:

```
altList = origList
```

In Python, assignment of a list like this only performs a "shallow copy"; altList just becomes another reference to the data in origList, rather than being a completely new copy.

To get what you want, try

```
from copy import deepcopy

altList = deepcopy(origList)
```

Comment: `altList = origList` is not a shallow copy, since it is not a copy at all. `altList = origList[:]` would be a shallow copy.